# Part number using imap_fetchbody not working?

Tags: php, parsing, email, encoding, imap

I've been playing around with this and can not get it to pull the correct part of the message to be inputted into the database.

I can get it to insert it when I use part number 1 or part number 2. But neither does what I am looking for. I want to pull the html so that I retain my line breaks and such.

```
    $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {
  foreach($emails as $email_number) {
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,"1");
        $subject = $overview[0]->subject;
        createEvent($subject, $body, $email_number, $inbox);
  }
}

function createEvent($subject, $body, $msgNo, $inbox) { //process the body of the email and take it apart and find stuff in it...do whatever processing you need to here 
    $customer = ''; 
    $store    = ''; 
    $event    = ''; 
    $time = time();
    $status = '';

    // take the subject apart to get the individual elements 
    $split_subject = explode (":", $subject);

    $customer = trim($split_subject[1]);
    $store = trim($split_subject[3]);
    $event = trim(substr($split_subject[5], 0, 3));
    $status = substr($split_subject[5], 4);
    $priority = getPriority($event, $status);


    $amcs_db = mysqli_connect(AMCS_HOST, AMCS_USER, AMCS_PASS, AMCS_NAME) or die('Cannot connect to database');
    $message_body = mysqli_real_escape_string($amcs_db, $body);

    $sql = "INSERT into events values (0, '$customer', '$store', '$event', '$status', '$priority', '$time', '$body')";
    $result = mysqli_query($amcs_db, $sql) or die("Error writing to AMCS db");

    if ($result){ /*delete the email if the insertion was succesful*/
        //$delete = imap_delete($inbox, $msgNo);
        //imap_expunge($inbox);
    }
    mysqli_close($amcs_db);
}// end function
```

When using part number 1 I get plain text with no line breaks and everything looks correctly and is encoded right. when I use 2 it now has the line breaks but has some spots with "Errors:
=A0=A0=A0=A0=A0=A0=A0 = Sign # 1: error sign controller" showing. In the regular email it's formatted with errors on one line and the next line is then indented. So it seems like some type of issue with how that indention is being put into the email.

How can I correct this issue? If I use part number 2.2 or 1.2 it enters it into my DB blank and that's not what I want, lol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I still have not resolved the issue with using different part numbers but I figured out a solution. If I put it into the database using "1", when I echo it out it retains the line breaks when I use nl2br(). Hope that helps somebody.

I'd still love to know why it wasn't working though.
Thanks!